# How to add Javascript Origins dynamically for multiple clients in Google Developer Console?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I want to add Javascript Origins dynamically for multiple clients in Google Developer Console. I am creating multiple tenants in my SaaS based application that need Gmail module.

Comment: Your project in google developer console must be set up manually.  You will need to add each of your JS origins yourself.

Comment: I don't know if you can use the cloud shell or APIs for this. Have you tried using the cloud shell?

Comment: @Aerials i haven't tried cloud shell. I tried to find API but no luck.